# LaTeX beamer: Package keyval Error: 0.5cm undefined. \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, errors, miktex, texstudio

Recently, I am reading the book [1]. Today, I input the following code on page 794 of [1] into TeXstudio 3.1.2:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][0.5cm]
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\small,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=5.2ex,leftskip=.3cm,%
       rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,vmode]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle\strut
      \hfill\Huge\raisebox{-1ex}{FU}%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\empty\else\par
        {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{%
         \usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}%
         \insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{fu-berlin}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{The macro \texttt{\textbackslash setbeamertemplate}}
        \framesubtitle{how it works ...}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then I press the key F5 on the keyboard. The TeXstudio displays the following error message:

```
Line 23: Package keyval Error: 0.5cm undefined. \end{frame}
```

I have checked my code. I am sure that it is just the same as that on page 794 of [1]. I am a beginner at the beamer. Then I google the error message, but I cannot find the problem with the code. Do you know where is the problem? Thank you in advance.

Note: I use MiKTeX 2.9.

**Reference**

[1] M. Goossens, F. Mittelbach, S. Rahtz, D. Roegel, H. Voss, *The $\LaTeX$ Graphics Companion*, 2nd ed., Addison Wesley, 2008.

Comment: From where do you have that `\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][0.5cm]` is the correct syntax?

Comment: From what I can see in the manual that second `[]` option is a key-value list, to 0.5 is used without a key

Comment: @daleif I am not familiar with the command \setbeamertemplate, I am a beginner of beamer.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu I wasn't familiar with it either, but that was the only instance of `0.5cm` in your code, so it had to be that line....

Comment: Then I'd suggest you do not mess with the beamer settings

Comment: @David Carlisle OK, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @daleif OK, I understand. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> \setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][0.5cm]

looking at the beamer manual page 174 should be

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=0.5cm]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!